# BigQuery Dataset not shown after Logstash Job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, logstash

I am trying to upload some data from an Elasticsearch instance to BigQuery using Logstash and the BigQuery plugin.

The Logstash pipeline seems to work ok. No errors whatsoever and the logs indicate that the events are flushed to GBQ. What I am expecting at this point is the dataset to be available in my big query project but this does not happen.

I am not very familiar with Google Cloud Services so any advice on what to do next would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually successful uploads to BigQuery take some minutes to actuallize. 

Are you still not able to see any upload to BigQuery?, if not, could you please elaborate with some more clues how you execute this upload? code used, responses,etc.

Comment: I don't really know how logstash plugin sends data to bigquery under the hood, but in case it's using [streaming inserts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) it might take you up to 90' to actually see the data. Still, you should be able to run queries on them during this time. This is actually an easy way to check whether this the root cause - when you don't see data in the destination table as expected, try a select * and if **do** get results, just give it some time.